# Two conditions on one formula field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I have a field, which takes values less than zero & greater than zero.

Also in that field, Values will be having leading zeros.

So I have used the following conditions like

```
Replace({Command. Field}, "0",".") and

If {Command. Field} < 0 
then ((Int(tonumber({command. Field}))) *1000)
```

When I save the formula getting error like "A Boolean is required here"

Why I am getting this error?

Since this field has values less than zero & I want to automatically multiple that value with 1000 to get the desired output.

Is it possible to give both of the conditions in single formula?

Comment: Are you putting this formula into a Formula Field or a Format Expression (X-2 button on a field property)?  Also, what is the data type for `{Command.Field}`?

Comment: Data type for {command.Field} is nvarchar

Comment: What about the formula?  Are you creating a Formula Field, or are you placing `{Command.Field}` within a section of the report and then editing one of it's properties?

Comment: I want to place the formula field in details section

Comment: I setup a report in my system with similar parameters.  A formula field using your formula that gets values from a nvarchar field in my test database.  However, I'm unable to get the same error as you.  Instead the error I'm receiving is on the expression for the If statement because it is trying to compare a string (nvarchar) as less than zero (an integer).  If I get the boolean error, I'll come back with an update.